# Stepper Motor power supplies

Tags: power

Being new to the world of stepper motors, I have a [Longs](http://www.longs-motor.com) Stepper Motor 23HS9430 bought from eBay it's a 3.0 A 5 V motor.

Although I have been reading about the supply voltage for the motor, the controller I have, again from eBay, has a supply voltage of 9-42 V DC.

What would be the best controller and supply voltage to run the stepper? The application is a antenna controller with a worm drive gearbox connected to the hardware that moves the antennas.

Comment: 24 is optimal, 42 if you have problems holding position.

Comment: Assuming by controller, you mean a stepper driver....if you dont have one, gecko drivers are highly recommended...assuming budget isn’t a huge concern. How do you intend to send steps/dir signals to the controller/driver

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be things clarified:

In short: there are 3 components needed for control. A motor, a driver, and a power supply.

When you want to use a stepper motor in a project, you need to use a stepper driver. A stepper driver takes in the STEP and DIR(ection) signals to modulate the pulses to the motor. When you are looking at the specifications of the stepper motor, what you need is a stepper driver that can power the current requirements (amperes) of the motor. Once you have a stepper driver that can supply the required current, you then need to find a power supply that can power the stepper driver.

My suspicion is that the power supply you have is okay, but you need to pick out a stepper driver still. This is where I cannot answer, but rather *suggest* companies that make these sort of things. [Circuit Specialists](https://www.circuitspecialists.com/stepper-motor-drivers) has stepper drivers that would fit your needs as they have high current and high precision. I suggest you do more research as any further answering would be opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

The power supply voltage of hybrid stepping motor driver is generally in a wide range (for example, the power supply voltage of mc425 is 12 ~ 36VDC). The power supply voltage is usually selected according to the working speed and response requirements of the motor If the working speed of the motor is high or the response is required to be fast, the voltage value is also high, but note that the ripple of the power supply voltage cannot exceed the maximum input voltage of the driver, otherwise the driver may be damaged

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend adhering to the specs of the motor for power supply.

Please see the following for driver:

1. [AMIS-30543 Stepper Motor Driver Carrier](https://www.pololu.com/product/2970)
2. [3A UNIPOLAR STEPPER MOTOR DRIVER](http://www.electronics-lab.com/project/3a-unipolar-stepper-motor-driver/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please [edit] your answer to explain why it is right. Additionally, we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. [*link only*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/) answers are frowned upon (as links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)) & will be rendered useless if the linked-to content disappears. If you add more context and detail from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.